# Magento product: remove SKU from product name

Tags: php, mysql, magento, replace

Currently I've got a shop with the SKU included in the product name, now I want to remove this from the product name, but how should I do this?

I found these query's to list product name and sku but how can I use TRIM(REPLACE(product_name, SKU, '')) with these? Or is there a better way than run mysql queries in phpmyadmin?

```
SELECT `value` AS product_name
FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar
WHERE entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product') 
AND attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'name' AND entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
```

AND

```
SELECT `sku` FROM `catalog_product_entity`
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to filter according to the store id , replace the store id in the your_store_id  with the store you want

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->->addAttributeToFilter('store_id',"your_store_id")
                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'sku'));

foreach ($products as $product) {

echo  "old name".$product->getName();
    $product->setName(str_replace($product->getSku(), '', $product->getName()))->save();
echo  "new name".$product->getName();
}
```

Comment: Changed it into: [code]<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(2);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'sku'));

$i = 1;
foreach ($products as $product) {
echo '<hr>';
echo  "$i old name: ".$product->getName().'<br>';
    $product->setName(trim(str_replace($product->getSku(), '', $product->getName())))->save();

    echo 'New: '.str_replace($product->getSku(), '', $product->getName()).'<br>';
    
    $i++;
}[/code]

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'sku'));

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product->setName(str_replace($product->getSku(), '', $product->getName()))->save();
}
```

Save this in your `public_html` folder and run it by visiting the url. If it runs successfully, the page should finish loading and be blank. It could take a little bit if your catalog is significantly large.

Comment: Thank you! Thats what Im looking for. Also thank you to Rohit Goel. Whats in your opinion the best way to learn Magento development?

Comment: Sorry, another question, I got 2 languages installed (2 store views) how should I work with this script?

Answer (score 1):

you can also see it by priniting the old and new name in loop

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'sku'));

foreach ($products as $product) {

echo  "old name".$product->getName();
    $product->setName(str_replace($product->getSku(), '', $product->getName()))->save();
echo  "new name".$product->getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you can write some php code on your server to do that, first get all products collection, then for each product, get product name, replace SKU with '',then set product name back and save.